# Android Lollipop Wifi Socket java.net.ConnectException ETIMEDOUT

Tags: android, sockets, timeout

I'm trying to connect to a socket like this:

```
    try {
        Server = "192.168.0.10";
        port = 7000;

        System.out.println("SOCKET: Create Socket: " + Server+ ":" + port);

        socket = new Socket(Server, port);

        System.out.println("SOCKET: Created Socket: " );

        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        in = socket.getInputStream();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("SOCKET: CATCH: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

This works fine on my Android 4.2 device. If I test the same code on Android Lollipop (5.x) I'll get the following Errors:

```
05-20 08:25:59.592: E/Con(8167): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.10 (port 7000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-20 08:25:59.592: E/Con(8167):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
05-20 08:25:59.592: E/Con(8167):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
05-20 08:25:59.592: E/Con(8167):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
05-20 08:25:59.592: E/Con(8167):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:590)
05-20 08:25:59.592: E/Con(8167):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
05-20 08:25:59.592: E/Con(8167):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
05-20 08:25:59.592: E/Con(8167):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
```

In both cases my Android devices are connected with the same device over wifi. Does anyone know the problem with Lollipop?

Thanks!!

**EDIT: WORKAROUND:
Well, I noticed a weird behaviour: If I turn off my mobile internet data the Socket is being created! But I just need the mobile data, so it is not a satisfying solution... Any Ideas on how to create the socket with mobile data activated?**

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm dealing with a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same problem. We solved it like this:

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) Context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkRequest.Builder nb = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
nb.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);

conMan.requestNetwork(nb.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    @Override
                    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                        Socket s = new Socket();
                        network.bindSocket(s);

                        s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(server, port));
                    }
                });
```

Using Network.bindSocket(Socket) you can actively choose the network you want to use for that socket. This is necessary since starting with Lollipop the systems default network is one with connection to the internet.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try next week and mark it as solved if it works! Thank you very much!